# Regular Expression Notepad++ How do I delete a portion of text in a line without deleting the rest of the line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have lines of CNC code that look like this:

```
N82 X-.4698 Y4.6023 Z0. C0. B180.
N83 X-.4688 Y4.637 Z0. C0. B180.
N84 X-.4748 Y4.67 Z0. C0. B180.
N85 X-.4876 Y4.7037 Z0. C0. B180.
```

I want to find all the Y values like Y4.6023 and replace them with nothing. I have been using regular expressions but when I replace it deletes the Y value along with the rest of the line.

Can anyone write a regular expression that will work for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Why are you not doing a simple/normal search that replaces Y with nothing?

Comment: Like `Y[0-9.]+ `?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio a normal search like that will just remove Y and leave all the following numbers which is not what the OP wants

Comment: The answer provided by Toto has worked perfectly.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bY\S+\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # word boundary, to avoid replacing BY...
Y       # letter Y
\S+     # 1 or more non space
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This worked great.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @raceem30: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)